# Google App Engine urlfetch PayloadTooLargeError: Request exceeds 10 MiB limit for URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Google App Engine's google.appengine.api.urlfetch is throwing the error:

PayloadTooLargeError: Request exceeds 10 MiB limit for URL

Is there a way to increase the max payload size?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so because `urlfetch` which you have to use on AppEngine to issue outbound HTTP request is limited to 10MB max payload.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests#quotas_and_limits_for_url_fetch